# Помогите поправить массив php

Tags: php, массивы

Я новичок в php... Но пытаюсь полученные данные привести к определенному виду массива..Мой скрипт извлекает данные из XML и записывает 
 их массив в CSV файл  в виде:

```
    Array
(
    [Code] => 209113
    [URL] => https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/490432-1.jpg
)
Array
(
    [Code] => 209125
    [URL] => https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/489002-new.jpg
)
Array
(
    [Code] => 205366
    [URL] => https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/477802-new.jpg
)
Array
(
    [Code] => 205366
    [URL] => https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/477803-new.jpg
)
Array
(
    [Code] => 209116
    [URL] => https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/493445-new.jpg
)
```

с помощью вот такого скрипта

```
   $start = microtime(true);
   $fpfinal = fopen(__DIR__.'/PicURlbyCode.csv','w+');
   $headers = array ('Code','link');
   fputcsv($fpfinal,$headers,';','"');


  foreach(glob(__DIR__."/PicList/*.xml") as $FileName){                                           
  $items = array();
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($FileName);

 foreach($xml->Product as $product){

     $items= get_object_vars($product);

     fputcsv($fpfinal,$items,';','"');

 } 

  } fclose($fpfinal);    

  echo (memory_get_usage(true));
  echo 'Время выполнения скрипта: '.round(microtime(true) - $start, 4).' сек.';
```

как видите CODE повторяется а ссылки URL разные, Помогите  привести массив $items  к виду

```
    Array
(
    [Code] => 205366
    [URL] => https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/477802-new.jpg
    [URL2] => https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/477803-new.jpg
)
```

как бы один код и к нему несколько ссылок...а не 1 и тот же  код одна ссылка... и ЗАПИСАТЬ ВСЕ в CSV файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально имеем следующий многомерный массив:

```
$array = [
    ['Code' => '209113', 'URL' => 'https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/490432-1.jpg'],
    ['Code' => '209125', 'URL' => 'https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/489002-new.jpg'],
    ['Code' => '205366', 'URL' => 'https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/477802-new.jpg'],
    ['Code' => '205366', 'URL' => 'https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/477803-new.jpg'],
    ['Code' => '209116', 'URL' => 'https://source.dclink.com.ua/images/493445-new.jpg']
];
```

*Первый способ*, он прекрасно работает, но я считаю, что он слишком запутан:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $new[$value['Code']][] = $value['URL'];
}

foreach ($new as $key => $value)
{
    $new[$key] = [];

    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
        $new[$key]['URL'.(($k + 1) > 1 ? $k + 1 : false)] = $value[$k];
    }
}

$i = 0;

foreach ($new as $key => $value)
{
    $data[$i]['Code'] = $key;

    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
        $data[$i][$k] = $v;
    }

    $i++;
}

print_r($data);
```

*Второй способ*, более упрощенный и оптимальный вариант, как по мне:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $row)
{
    if (!isset($result[$row['Code']]))
    {
        $result[ $row['Code'] ] = [
            'Code' => $row['Code'],
            'URL' => $row['URL']
        ];
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$row['Code']]['URL'.count($result[$row['Code']])] = $row['URL'];
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: помогите  записать  многомерный массив который получился в результате в CSV файл...

Comment: Покажите примерно в каком формате нужно произвести запись?

Comment: код;изобрражение1;жизобраение2;изображение3(если оно есть)                                                                
      foreach ($result as $fields) {
          fputcsv($fp, $fields);
      }   вообщем используя функцию  fputcsv

Comment: @МихаилАнискин, сейчас не могу вам сделать это, можете отставить вопрос новый, если вам это нужно, либо же я завтра вернусь

Comment: да мне не срочно...если сможете то завтра мне помочь...Я буду ОЧЕНЬ признателен)

Comment: @МихаилАнискин, тогда завтра

Comment: @МихаилАнискин, вам нужно именно фотографией вставлять?

Comment: ну как бы да...я использую модуль для добавлений товаров в опенкaрт Total Import PRO  а в нем можно довавлять изображения только отдельными столбцами в csv формате.. Код;изображение1;изображение 2(если оно есть);изображение 3 (если оно есть ) и так далее ...а в товарах есть как всего 1 изображение так и больше 10ти...и как это реализовать я не знаю..

Comment: @МихаилАнискин, посмотрите на этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/6016736/9981750

Comment: это не подходит